# Is there any way to avoid Gödel incompleteness theorem?

Tags: logic, foundations, incompleteness

I was wondering whether there have been successful attempts to avoid somehow the incompleteness theorem.
Many point out that every language that is powerful enough to model natural numbers can produce a godel-type sentence. But my point is that it's actually a METAmathematical strategy that Godel uses (as he says in the first pages of his paper). Arithmetic doesn't contain itself the predicate 'provable'. So basically I'm asking: can we avoid such inconsistencies just forbidding to represent any predicate like 'provable' unless moving to a higher-predicate metalanguage?

Comment: You don't need a "provable" predicate for GIT to hold. Sure, Godel's original proof may use it, but there have been several simplifications of the ideas of the proof which remove this requirement.

Comment: No "inconsistencies" at all...

Comment: The proof is a standard mathematical proof showing that in a formal system with specified properties (consistency, etc) there is an undecidable sentence. [More examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem) without "provability" predicate.

Comment: Well you could bypass the incompleteness theorem by choosing only to work in a complete theory like the theory of real-closed fields, but it would be very limiting: e.g., you couldn't do number theory.

Comment: Ok thanks, but maybe mine is a somewhat more philosophical question. The paris-harringhton theorem is provable in secon-order logic. One can show that since ramsey's th would imply the consistency of PA it cannot be proved in PA. But we know that PA is inconsistent by godel theorem, and it sounds a little circular. But maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @DonThousand thank you, could you tell me where to find some examples that don't use the 'provable' predicate?

Comment: @nskywalker “We know that PA is inconsistent by Gödel’s theorem”... did you mean to say this ?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen sorry i meant incomplete

Answer (score 2):

As Don Thousand and Mauro ALLEGRANZA pointed out, there are ways to circumvent the need for a provability predicate. A systematic method to go about constructing true but unprovable statements would use that every theory has an [ordinal strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis) $\alpha$, then construct a set $S$ which is well ordered, with [order type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) $\beta\ge\alpha$. Then, encode the statement "$S$ is [well ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)" into that system. This gives a true but unprovable statement. An example of this can be found at https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.14342. I know of two ways to circumvent Gödel's incompleteness theorem:

1. A weak theory. Gödel's incompleteness theorem only applies to sufficiently strong systems. It is not applicable to systems like [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) and [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).
2. An inconsistent theory. This pretty much goes without saying, see [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)

Comment: I think for 1, it is better to say "a weak language".  Weakening a logic doesn't increase the "completeness" .

Comment: A slogan to summarize 1: To avoid incompleteness, don't do anything complicated like integer arithmetic.

Comment: Than you very much, I'm going to investigate this subject more deeply!

Comment: Surely first-order logic is strong enough to encode Robinson's system $Q$ and hence has sentences that are true but unprovable.

Comment: @RobArthan In a sense you're right, but the OP is also right. Pure FOL (= the empty theory in FOL) is not **essentially incomplete**, so in that sense Godel doesn't apply; all the finite axiomatizability of $\mathsf{Q}$ tells us is that the set of FOL tautologies is as complicated as the deductive closure of $\mathsf{Q}$, and so FOL is undecidable, but this to my mind falls well short of saying that Godel applies.